# Not able to push in an JSON array in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I'm using a session variable array of JSON objects to get a list of dynamic data from HTTP url.

this is my component.ts code:

```
import { IProduct } from "../models/iproduct";
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TimerObservable } from "rxjs/observable/TimerObservable";
import {  
  Http  
} from '@angular/http';   
import {  
  ProcessJsonService  
} from '../models/myjsonprocess';  
import {  
  Observable  
} from 'rxjs/Rx'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  pageTitle: string = 'Process List';
  imageWidth: number = 50;
  imageMargin: number = 2;
  showImage: boolean = false;
  listFilter: string = '';
  processList: IProduct[]  ;
  mysessionvariable: IProduct[] ;
  errorMessage: string;
      private alive: boolean;
    private interval: number
  constructor(private _processJsonService: ProcessJsonService) {  
    this.processList = []; 
    this.mysessionvariable = [];
        this.alive = true;
        this.interval = 1000;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
        TimerObservable.create(0, this.interval)
          .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
          .subscribe(() => {
            this._processJsonService.getProcesslist()
              .subscribe(processList => {
            if (processList instanceof Array) {
                this.processList = processList;
                this.mysessionvariable =  this.SaveDataToLocalStorage(processList);
                this.processList = this.mysessionvariable; 
            } else {
                this.processList = [processList];
               this.mysessionvariable =  this.SaveDataToLocalStorage(processList);
               this.processList = this.mysessionvariable; 
            }  

              });
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.alive = false;
    }

     SaveDataToLocalStorage(data)
{
    var mysessionarray: any[] = Array.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')));
    // Parse the serialized data back into an aray of objects
  // localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(data));
    // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
    //console.log("my mysessionarray is", mysessionarray)
    console.log("my data in push is", data)
    mysessionarray.push(data);
    //localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(mysessionarray));
    console.log("my data after push is", mysessionarray)
    return mysessionarray;
}
}
```

This is my service:

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Http,
  HttpModule,
  Headers,
  RequestOptions,
  Response
} from '@angular/http';
import {
  HttpClientModule
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; //get everything from Rx    
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {
  IProduct
} from "../models/iproduct";
@Injectable()
export class ProcessJsonService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  //    
  getProcesslist(): Observable < IProduct[] > {
    let url = 'myURL';
    return this.http.request(url).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: mysessionarray.push is not a function
> at ProductListComponent.SaveDataToLocalStorage (product-list.component.ts:71)
> at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (product-list.component.ts:50)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
> at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
> at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
> at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
> at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
> ```

Please any help on getting this fixed? am I missing some imports? or please what's wrong with my code?

Also, how to refresh data in the JSON array means when a new JSON's data are added I need if this row exists in my array just update its data else add a new row?

Comment: Are you able to verify that is actually an Array? Seems like `mysessionarray `is not an array since push is on the prototype.

Comment: is this is not the correct declaration of an array var mysessionarray: any[]; (sorry I'm beginner in Angular 4. or the problem in my ngOnInit() ?? I only use this declaration to define my array var mysessionarray: any[];

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof mysessionarray);` before that push statement. If it's array then only you can push otherwise not.

Comment: yes it's not an array...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `JSON.parse` method to convert your `JSON` data into `Typescript object`.

```
mysessionarray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
```

But it will not convert into array directly as your `localStorage.getItem('session')` may return JSON object as well.

If you are sure that you will get `JSON Array` only then you can specify

```
mysessionarray: any[] = Array.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')));
```

It will vary on data which it receives. Hope it helps  !!

Comment: typescript object?

Comment: Angular4 can be coded in JS and TS. By looking at syntax it seems to be TypeScript. So I said typescript object or more clearly 'typescript array object'

Comment: Rohan your answer works in some way. What I'm getting now is a table of two rows the first row contains the new JSON and the second one contails tyhe old JSON of the first row. means as if I'm getting table wher ethe first row is an array of JSON objects and the second row contains the old JSON of the first row. I doupt about my declarations of ProcessList and mysessionarray in the service.

Comment: you can convert one specific object into array and use it for your purpose . Suppose you have two keys in JSON object with name 'normalJson' and 'arrayJSON'. so you can fetch arrayJSON key data and pass to Array.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session').arrayJSON)). Please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Hello, you tried the change I suggested and did it worked for you ?

Comment: sorry for not answering you. a lot of work :( So, now I'm getting the first row of the table always having the same data and the second row is showing the new json. Means if a new JSON is here, the data of the second row of my table are updated by the new JSON data not an other row is added.... Still looking on that I also updated by question by the latest version of the code.